# Node.js modules not building in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

I'm building this dockerfile using docker-compose and I need it to build native modules in docker (not just copy them from local). This only works when my local modules are built (npm install) As soon as I delete them this runs but there is no node_modules directory and it gives an error: Error: Cannot find module 'express'

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:6
MAINTAINER Me

COPY package.json index.js lib /app/

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache make gcc g++ python && \
  addgroup -S app && adduser -S -g app app && \
  npm install && \
  npm cache clean && \
  apk del make gcc g++ python

USER app
```

And here is the app directory:

```
.dockerignore
.eslintignore
.eslintrc.js
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
index.js
lib
npm-debug.log
package.json
```

Comment: I think adding your package.json could provide some more insight.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the way docker binds the app folder from the host to the container. The second line in the volume section from my docker-compose.yml fixed it.

```
volumes:
  - .:/app
  - /app/node_modules
```